# Select and get contents of a span with same class as other elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple but it's turning out more difficult than I thought.

I have on a page 4 span elements (that I have no control over) all with the same class ID (**BOfSxb**) and I need to edit only two of them - the second and the 4th element.  So I'm not sure how to select only those two and before I do that, I need to know the contents of the 2nd or the 4th span element (2 and 4 have identical content).  I figured out how to get the contents but I'm getting both combined so if the content is 2,304,400 I'm getting back 2,304,4002,304,400

here's how I was able to get the content so far:

```
var spanContent = $("span.BOfSxb:contains(2,304,400)").text()

console.log(spanContent); //returns 2,304,4002,304,400 ( I need 2,304,400)
```

The other problem with the above is **:contains** has a number I won't know ahead of time.

After I get the content off the second or 4th span, I need to compare it and see what range it falls under and do something else with it.  Something like:

```
if ($(".BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").text() >= 0 && $(".BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").text() <= 1000) {

$("span.BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").replaceWith(finalDiv);

} else if ($(".BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").text() >= 1001 && $(".BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").text() <= 1000000) {

$("span.BOfSxb:contains("+ spanContent + ")").replaceWith(finalDiv2);

} else {

//something else
}
```

EDIT: I should add this is actually a Chrome extension that will be doing the editing of the span elements on a page I have no control over.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added this is going to be a Chrome extension that will edit these elements on a website.  I'm not sure if jsfiddle will work in this case.

Comment: You could use the n-th child selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the element to grab by using it's index number in relation to it's class. You can do this with the jquery `.eq()` method.

```
$(".span.BOfSxb").eq(1).text();
$(".span.BOfSxb").eq(3).text();
```

You can then use the `parseInt();` method to change them into numbers and add them if you wish. The parseInt() method returns an integer from a string. When you get the text from the elements they are not able to be added together because they are not considered numbers, they are considered text strings.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atw5z0ch/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, this should work:

HTML:

```
<span class="span">1234</span>
<span class="span">Other content 1</span>
<span class="span">1234</span>
<span class="span">Other content 2</span>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
var content = '1234';
// Notice:
// (i) content is a string. You should use quotes if you 
// directly write the value, as specified here: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
// (ii) Using classes to select objects with jQuery will return an array of elements
var spans = $('.span:contains(' + content + ')');

spans.each(function(i){
    var value = parseInt($(this).text());
    if(value > 0 && value < 1000){
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3tbag1qs/2/

UPDATE: as @zfrisch suggests, you can also get the spans by their positions. The solution presented here is another way to solve your problem, if you are not sure of the exact order.

Comment: It seems like the span variable is returning the index number of the span tag in your fiddle, not the element. I got it to work using eq() http://jsfiddle.net/3tbag1qs/1/

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about the error. However, I think is much better to use the 'each' function instead of asking jQuery to search again for .span elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-of-type` selector. It probably wont work in older browsers though.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/